# Servidor DNS, Ubuntu y Webmin

Tags: ubuntu, servidor, dns

He estado trabajando en servidor DNS, con ubuntu server, bind9, mi ip publica y mi dominio.
Termino de configurar la zona y todo en el webmin, y no me devuelve errores, el problema es que luego al hacerle nslookup en el cmd no me devuelve nada,
Por lo que creo que el problema es el redireccionamiento
Adjunto las imagenes de mi modem y configuracion de ens38 de ubuntu
Espero me puedan ayudar, ya que no logro dar con el funcionamiento del servidor
  *La ip con la que abro los puertos del modem esta libre en mi lan
  *La puerta de enlace de mi modem es 192.168.0.1
  *Tengo la ip publica amarrada al modem.
  *La ip que sale en el ubuntu 192.168.0.20, es la misma que abre los puertos.
  *En el nameservers va mi public ip
PDS: en un comentario dejara la foto del ubuntu[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso es lo que hay en el ubuntu en el /etc/network/interfaces en la parte del ens38

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer que ubuntu resuelva DNS en 127.0.0.1 y en el archivo de configuración del bind9 pon un forwarding a 8.8.8.8 u otro servidor público de DNS.